# cxf rest service from interface definition(without implementation)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I want to expose rest services with cxf with a custom invoker logic which will proxy the remote service call. However as far as I see it can not be done without a concrete service class which is not necessary in my case. Is there any way to do this ?

```
@Path(value = "/hi2")
public interface Service2 {
    @GET
    public Response hello();
}
```

And the server definition :

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean server = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
            Class<?> clas = Class.forName(s);
            server.setInvoker(new MyInvoker());
            server.setAddress("/rest"+count.incrementAndGet());
            server.setResourceClasses(clas);
            //server.setResourceProvider(clas,new SingletonResourceProvider(clas));
            server.create();
```